# Character extract challenge

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, arraylist

MY database value for bus column. 12,34,56,8,9, ... im trying to extract only the bus numbers and not the commas and adding them to a String ArrayList. Anyone have any idea? :

im really confuse. heres my code:

```
for(int i =0; i< buses1.length() ; i++ )
{
        if(buses1.charAt(i) == ',')
        {



        }
        else
        {
            bus1 += Character.toString(buses1.charAt(i));
            buses.add(bus1);
        }
}
```

at this point, the codes are adding like this, "1", "2" , "3" , "4" not "12", "34" ....
Any one have any ideal?

Comment: I guess you want a tokenizer

Comment: Why don't you use `split` method? Which is very easier than you're trying

Comment: `String[] busNumbers = databaseValue.split(",");`

Comment: Thanks guys appreciate reallly helped now i can move on with my project!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of your current logic. You just need [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))  with delimeter as `","`  which returns your bus numbers as a array.

The below line is enough

```
String[] numbers = columnValue.split(",");
```

Then your ArrayList delcaration turns

```
List<String> busesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

Comment: You could use `Arrays.asList(numbers)` if you want to keep the Strings in a `List<String>`. I have to mention that this operation would be by far less expensive than just looping the array and manually add each element to the list.

Comment: @Daniel I'm on the way daniel :) just did a edit while you are commenting.

Comment: @Daniel Can you please check `asList` docs ???  that `Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array`

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to split the String by using the ',' delimiter.

```
List<String> buses = Arrays.asList(buses1.split(","));
```

EDIT: Make sure that by doing so, `buses` will be an unmodifiable list( a list where you cannot add/remove elements to/from it). If you need a modifiable list, you can easily wrap it into one :

```
List<String> buses = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(buses1.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained the recommended what to solve this problem.  I just want to point out why your current attempt fails.

To get the effect you describe, it must actually be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buses1.length(); i++ ) {
    String bus1 = "";
    if (buses1.charAt(i) == ',') {
    } else {
        bus1 += Character.toString(buses1.charAt(i));
        buses.add(bus1);
    }
}
```

The problem is that you are adding a "bus" to the list at the wrong point.  You need to add it when you've got the last character of a (single- or multi-digit) bus number.  But you are adding it for each digit.

Your code actually needs to be something like this:

```
String bus1 = "";
for (int i = 0; i < buses1.length(); i++ ) {
    if (buses1.charAt(i) == ',') {
      // When we see a comma, we know that is the end of the bus number.
      if (!bus1.isEmpty()) {
          buses.add(bus1);
          bus1 = "";
      }
    } else {
        // Accumulate the digits of the current bus number.
        bus1 += Character.toString(buses1.charAt(i));
    }
}
// Deal with stuff after the last comma.
if (!bus1.isEmpty()) {
    buses.add(bus1);
}
```

Note that we could improve on that in a couple of important ways.  But it is easier to see the relationship with your (hypothesized) original code with this version.